# Super Slow Visual Studio

Tags: process, visual-studio-2010

My Visual Studio 2010 professional is running super slowly. (This is during normal operation, not debugging or anything) I checked all the processes that were started by it in a program called [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

This is what I found:
[image]

There are hundreds of processes every second with a path called "C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6\namespace\hera". (hera is the server that I opened the source code from) This results in "NAME NOT FOUND".

Any suggestions of how I can prevent these processes?

Comment: I can't see the process list because SU resized the image. Post a link to a higher resolution version.

Comment: @Mikhail: The process name is `devenv.exe` over and over again.  The truncated times are more of a problem than the small size.

Comment: BTW, there's only one process here, making many I/O calls.  "Process" has a very specific meaning in the computer world, and it doesn't mean "any task" the way the English word does.

Comment: @Mikhail: You can always view the image by itself; it's not resized permanently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding your subtle clues right, you opened a project from a network share or mapped network drive, so that **your working copy is stored on another machine**?

That will definitely slow things down.  Visual Studio uses a number of <strike>temporary</strike> auto-generated database files to cache symbol information, and it stores these in the project directory.  The latency of network access to what's supposed to be a fast local cache is killing your productivity.

**Make a local copy** if you want reasonable performance.  **Use version control** to keep the copies in sync (versioning has other benefits as well).  It's really easy to get started with subversion, but there are other options.

(CSC is the client side cache, part of the Windows "Offline Folders" feature.  It's not enabled for this server, which is causing the "Name Not Found" results.)

Final note: don't put the auto-generated databases into version control.  Regenerating them should be faster than repeated transferring them from the repository.

Comment: Yeah, I used to just check projects out of change control and operate on them on the server. Now I sandbox them on my local machine and they run nice and snappy :)